# Accessible drawer menu using tabs

Tags: html, accessibility

How to enable a user to tab through an app drawer immediately once the menu opens. In a menu similar to the following example (but having the drawer on the right):

[image]

Now I want the user to be able to tab through the application and have the focus on the menu directly once it opens.

**Desired outcome:**

- User presses tab
- [Focus is on the "open menu" button]
- User presses spacebar
- [Menu opens]
- User presses tab again
- [Focus is on the "close menu" icon]
- User presses tab again
- [Focus is on the first menu item] (*yay!*)

**Actual outcome:**

- User presses tab
- [Focus is on the "open menu" button]
- User presses spacebar
- [Menu opens]
- User presses tab again
- [Focus is on the first button ("this is some button") in the page] (*Oh no :(. it should instead be going to the navigation in the drawer*)

### Code example

For this code example I am following the steps as described on ["Navigation Menu Button Example"](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/examples/menu-button/menu-button-links.html) from w3.org.

```js
/* this JS code is arbitrary and for demonstration purpose. */
/* It is most likely a HTML solution */
const buttonOpenMenu = document.getElementById('open-menu');
const buttonCloseMenu = document.getElementById('close-menu');
const drawer = document.getElementById('drawer');

buttonOpenMenu.onclick = function () {
 drawer.classList.add('open');
    drawer.setAttribute("aria-expanded", true);
}

buttonCloseMenu.onclick = function () {
 drawer.classList.remove('open');
    drawer.setAttribute("aria-expanded", false);
}
```

```css
/* CSS also arbitrary */
main {
  flex-grow: 1;
  width: 100%;
}

#drawer {
  width: 240px;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  left: auto;
  right: -240px;
}

#drawer.open {
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <header>
    <button
      id="open-menu"
      aria-haspopup="true"
      aria-controls="drawer"
    >
      open menu
    </button>
  </header>
  <h1>
    Title
  </h1>
  <section>
    <button>
      this is some button
    </button>
    <p>Some body content</p>
    <button>
      another button
    </button>
  </section>
</main>
<div id="drawer" aria-expanded="false">
   <button id="close-menu">
     close menu
  </button>
  <nav aria-labelledby="open-menu" role="menu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="/" role="menuitem">Menu item 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="/" role="menuitem">Menu item 2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason that your tab order isn't working the way you want is because it doesn't reflect the DOM order. Elements will receive focus in the order that they appear in the markup, unless you set the focus.

You can fix this by setting focus when the menu opens by using [HTMLElement.focus()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOrForeignElement/focus).

HTML:

Add an `id` and `tabindex` attributes to the `nav` element.

```
<nav id="nav" aria-labelledby="open-menu" role="menu" tabindex="0">
```

JAVASCRIPT:

Set the focus on the `nav` element using `document.getElementById`.

```
buttonOpenMenu.onclick = function () {
    drawer.classList.add('open');
    drawer.setAttribute("aria-expanded", true);
    document.getElementById("nav").focus();
}
```

See a working example here: https://jsfiddle.net/25nzpo76/

Comment: one quick suggestion, change the initial focus to the close button instead of adding a `tabindex` to your `<nav>` element. You shouldn't make containers focusable in most circumstances. Alternatively you could change it to `tabindex="-1"` instead of `tabindex="0"` so it is focusable programatically but doesn't appear in the tab order although my first suggestion would be preferable. OP - dont forget to return focus to the open button when you close the drawer and trap focus in your drawer as it acts like a modal in effect.